# PHP form handling; getting user friendly text on server side?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have an issue with PHP where I'm wondering how I could get the full string to a form response.

Form:

```
...
      <tr>
        <td>How did blah blah blah blah?</td>
        <td><textarea rows="4" cols="25" name="blah_blah_blah"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
...
```

How could I pass the full question (How did blah blah blah blah?) along with the POST request to the server?

Note: I'm not asking how to handle forms in PHP; I already know how to do that. I want to know how to send the client facing question with the submit in the post request.

Comment: The answers below will help you do just that. But I would suggest you have the questions on your server side instead: You can pass in the ID of the question only on your hidden input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to just add a hidden field:

```
<td>How did blah blah blah blah?
   <input type="hidden" name="question" value="How did blah blah blah blah?" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do something like that is to use a hidden input or in other words input of type hidden.

```
<input type="hidden" name="question_1" value="..." />
<textarea rows="4" cols="25" name="answer_1"></textarea>
```